# Save .xls file using Microsoft Office 12.0 Object Library

Tags: c#, com

How do you specify the file format as .xls and not .xlsx when saving an excel file in C# programatically?

I've tried using `Excel.XlFileFormat.xlXMLSpreadsheet`

Which enumeration type will save the spreadsheet as a 2000-2003 formatted excel spreadsheet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From 2007/2010 automation you want`Excel.XlFileFormat.xlExcel8` for a 2000-2003 `.xls`.

Answer (score 0):

I used `xlWorkbookNormal` in some old code. I can't see any documentation to support that, though.